# Error: operand size mismatch for `movq' in libc-start.c

Tags: debugging, assembly, gcc, x86-64, glibc

I'm encountering an issue while compiling a glibc-2.19 with gcc-12.1.0.
The error I'm facing is an "operand size mismatch for `movq'" in the "libc-start.c" file at line 200.

Here is the exact error message I receive:

> libc-start.c:200: Error: operand size mismatch for `movq'
> glibc-2.19/csu/libc-start.o] Error 1

Ref:
https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/glibc-2.19/csu/libc-start.c#L200

Here are some additional details:

Compiler version: gcc-12.1.0

GNU C Library (glibc) versions:

- glibc-2.19 (encountering the error)
- glibc-2.20 (builds successfully)

I have ensured that the architecture is compatible, as I am compiling for a 64-bit system, so the instruction should be valid.

I have attempted to search for similar issues or error reports specific to my version of glibc, but I haven't found any specific resolutions or workarounds.

I am seeking assistance from the community to further understand the root cause and potential solutions for this issue.

Could someone kindly elaborate on the nature of the operand size mismatch and provide insights into debugging glibc-related errors?

Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use `gcc -S` to get an assembly listing to see what the invalid instruction is exactly.

Answer (score 1):

> Compiler version: gcc-12.1.0

You are trying to compile GLIBC from 2014 ([release timeline](https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/Glibc%20Timeline)) with a compiler from 2022. In general that doesn't work -- every release of GLIBC builds with the versions of GCC from approximately the same date (plus or minus a year or two).

Even if you manage to fix the build problem, there is no guarantee that you'll get a working binary -- it is not uncommon to discover that newer compiler optimizations expose latent bugs, which get fixed in newer GLIBC versions.

Your best bet is to get a GCC version from 2014 (e.g. GCC-4.8.4), and use *it* to build GLIBC-2.19.

P.S. You may also have an http://xyproblem.info here -- why do you want to build GLIBC-2.19 in the first place?

Comment: I encountered an issue with glibc-2.19 when attempting to update gcc in my build system. As I am relatively new to gcc, I am seeking to understand the root cause of this problem.